# How to use index types in nested property names in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

Assuming a class that has the shape:

```
class MyClass {
  prop1: {
    method1();
    method2();
  }

  prop2: {
    method3();
    method4();
  }
}
```

Is there a way to access the deeply nested methods using square bracket notation? I'm trying the following with an index type for the properties, which gets me one level deep, but I don't know how to dynamically access the unique method names per property nested below:

```
type property = keyof MyClass;
const obj = new MyClass();
const prop: property = 'prop1';
const meth: string = 'method2';

obj[prop][meth]();
```

I receive a compile error: `Element implicity has any type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type ...`

I cant figure out how to correctly type the nested methods to be a valid option of the specified property.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'dynamic'? Limiting `prop` to be `keyof MyClass` means that it can't ever be anything other than the properties of `MyClass`, which means you aren't going to be able to assign a variable typed with `string` to it unless you either type cast or provide some custom type guards

Comment: I'm not sure why you're annotating anything at all here; if [you remove annotations it will work](https://tsplay.dev/Nn4ddW).  If you annotate as `string` then things of course break because the compiler can't verify that `meth` is appropriate (`const meth: string = 'notEvenOnce'` would be a problem, right?).  If you have a use case where removing annotations doesn't help, please provide a [mcve] of it; maybe you have a function body or something?  In which case that function might need to be generic.

Comment: Please fix syntax errors